# Select On COUNT < x in a relational database

Tags: sql, select, relational-database

I have the following 3 tables:

**TestGroup**
RecordNumber (pk)

**Test**
RecordNumber (pk)
TestGroupRecordNumber (fk)

**Result**
RecordNumber (pk)
TestRecordNumber (fk)

Basically, TestGroup is a group of tests, and each test contains a number of results. I want to select all TestGroups that have less than X results. What query will achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT TG.RecordNumber
FROM TestGroup TG
   LEFT JOIN Test T ON TG.RecordNumber = T.TestGroupRecordNumber 
   LEFT JOIN Result R ON T.RecordNumber = R.TestRecordNumber 
GROUP BY TG.RecordNumber
HAVING COUNT(R.TestRecordNumber) < X
```

I'd also use a `LEFT JOIN` in case the Test Groups have no results or no tests.

Answer (score 6):

You should use *having* clause:

```
SELECT count(1), tg.recordNumber FROM testgroup tg
LEFT JOIN test t ON t.TestGRoupRecordNumber = tg.recordNumber
LEFT JOIN result r ON r.testRecordNumber = t.recordNumber
GROUP by tg.recordNumber
HAVING count(1) < 10
```